# Wine doesn't detect a keyboard input

Tags: linux, virtualbox, keyboard, wine

### Virtualbox host module may broke your wine.

Hey! I've just fixed up a wine keyboard input after a few days of reflection. It was like this:

A few days ago I bought a digital guitar preamp (mooer preamp X2) which can be connected with a PC, but software available for Windows and Mac only. I've tried to install it with Wine, but this has no effect, wine doesn't see usbhid (let me know how to connect it with Wine, pls).

After all, I broke up, and just install virtualbox with oracle extensions and `virtualbox-host-dkms` aur package. Preamp of course determined. Few days have gone, and I noticed that the keyboard has stopped working in ARMA 2.

just in case my configuration:

- OS: Arch Linux x86_64
- Kernel: 5.18.16-zen1-1-zen and Linux arch 5.19.1-arch2-1
- DE: Plasma 5.25.4
- WM: KWin
- CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 3500U
- Wine: 7.15/7.14
- Virtualbox version: 6.1.36 r152435
- Virtual box module packeges:
  virtualbox-host-dkms-6.1.36-1 (bad),
  virtualbox-host-modules-arch-6.1.36-10 (good).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dug up piles of forums, but only now it became clear, that virtualbox host module `virtualbox-host-dkms` was cause of the issue.

I changed it to `virtualbox-host-modules-arch` and the keyboard has successfully determined. But after that virtualbox runs on vanilla linux kernel only (neither linux zen nor hardened, you can always change kernel-module package to previous).